# Check file name and copy to destination folder

Tags: batch, cmd.exe

I am currently trying to get a command line working.

The way it works is as follow:
It should check all files in folder and subfolder for a specific name and copy those files into another folder.

So far I tried

```
xcopy /d /y /s "D:\Test\Screenshot\pcd_*.jpg" "D:\Copy\pcd\"
```

The issue of that, if I use /s, it takes all folders into consideration as well and copies them too instead of files only.

So I came up with a for-loop and tried

```
for /r %d in (D:\Test\Screenshot\pcd_*.jpg) do xcopy /d /y "%d" "D:\Copy\pcd\"
```

yet without any luck. No error, simply nothing.

I hope someon has a solution and already want to thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Test using **`for /f`** instead **`for /r`**, also, replace **`xcopy`** to **`copy`** command:

---

```
cd /d "D:\Test\Screenshot\" && for /f tokens^=* %i in ('%__APPDIR__%where /r "." "pcd_*.jpg"')do copy /y "%~i" "D:\Copy\pcd\"
```

---